# Find the generator of $(Z,*)$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

let $Z$ be the set of integers

let $\ast\ $ be an operation defined on $Z$ by $a*b=a+b-1$ $\forall \ $ $a,b$ $\in \ $$Z$

Is $(Z,*)$ cyclic if so find the generator of $(Z,*)$.

I think it is not cyclic group since if it is $1$ its inverse same as $1$ therefore there is no generator but I am not sure if I am wrong correct me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the names of the numbers. So what if $1*1=1$? That just means you have a candidate for the identity element.

Comment: @Arthur I write it as an example because I fell that there is no generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1$ is the identity element of $(\Bbb Z,*)$, then it is natural that it is not a generator. However, $2$ *is* a generator of $(\Bbb Z,*)$. To see why, see that $2*2=3$, $2*3=4$, $2*4=5$ and so on…

Comment: but wait how do you represent $-2,-1 $

Comment: Well, the inverse of $2$ is $0$; the inverse of $3$ is $-1$ and so on…

Comment: They are inverse of elements of the form $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm glad I could help.